# Is there a way that the index page is the only access point to a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a website set for a couple who are getting married, but they want to keep the website private and accessible only to guests.

I have the index page password protected, but this does not protect any of the other pages on to this website. Now I can of course, password protect every page, but the couple have asked me not to do that, because they don't want their guests typing a password every time the open up a new page.

So is there a way I can hide/block/denied access to all the other pages except the index page or that the index page is the only access point to the website.

Comment: after they successfully sign in assign them a session code. Check the session code for validity on the marriage page.

Comment: You haven't stated if  your are using any server side code or framework or CMS to produce the "website". It's not really possible to give you an answer without knowing that.

Comment: Please tell us what technologies you're using to make this website.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a **session** - a session lets users sign in once, and then uses a cookie or an authentication token to remember that user **x** is signed in on the machine that provides the cookie or token. However, it doesn't seem like you should be having to implement these things yourself. It would be helpful to provide more detail in your question about the technologies you're using. As a rule of thumb, you don't want to be implementing passwords, sessions, etc. by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your server runs an Apache web server then ..

Create two files.

`.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`

Within `.htaccess` you should put:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Make sure you update the path so it points to your `.htpasswd` file

Inside the `.htpasswd` file you need the valid logins.

e.g.

```
test:dGRkPurkuWmW2
```

As the pasword is encryped then use a tool like http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/ to generate the file for you.

Once you've uploaded both files then a new user will need to log in once and then after this they'll be able to browse the site without re-entering the login details.